# Rollback changes done to a MariaDB database by a spring test without @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions, mariadb

I have a Spring service that does something like that :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public void doStuff(UUID id) {
        // call an external service, via http for example, can be long
        // update the database, with a transactionTemplate for example
    }

}
```

The Propagation.NEVER indicates we must not have an active transaction when the method is called because we don't want to block a connection to the database while waiting for an answer from the external service.

Now, how could I properly test this and then rollback the database ? @Transactional on the test won't work, there will be an exception because of Propagation.NEVER.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public void testDoStuff() {
       putMyTestDataInDb();
       myService.doStuff();    // <- fails no transaction should be active
       assertThat(myData).isTheWayIExpectedItToBe();
    }

}
```

I can remove the @Transactional but then my database is not in a consistent state for the next test.

For now my solution is to truncate all tables of my database after each test in a @AfterEach junit callback, but this is a bit clunky and gets quite slow when the database has more than a few tables.

**Here comes my question :  how could I rollback the changes done to my database without truncating/using @Transactional ?**

The database I'm testing against is mariadb with testcontainers, so a solution that would work only with mariadb/mysql would be enough for me. But something more general would be great !

(another exemple where I would like to be able to not use @Transactional on the test : sometimes I want to test that transaction boundaries are correctly put in the code, and not hit some lazy loading exceptions at runtime because I forgot a @Transactional somewhere in the production code).

Some other precisions, if that helps :

- I use JPA with Hibernate
- The database is create with liquibase when the application context starts

---

Others ideas I've played with :

- @DirtiesContext : this is a lot slower, creating a new context is a lot more expensive than just truncating all tables in my database
- MariaDB SAVEPOINT : dead end, it's just a way to go back to a state of the database INSIDE a transaction. This would be the ideal solution IMO if i could work globally
- Trying to fiddle with connections, issuing `START TRANSACTION` statements natively on the datasource before the test and `ROLLBACK` after the tests : really dirty, could not make it work

Comment: if you use TestContainers, why would you want to rollback the data?

Comment: With TestContainers the db is empty for the complete suite of tests at the start only, but each test will pollute the db with its own data, potentially affecting other tests. I could use @DirtiesContext to have a new instance of mariadb for each test but that is even slower (a new spring context is expensive to create compared to truncating tables)

Comment: Service method `doStuff` does not rollback because this is your desired behavior, so you should not test any other behavior than that.

Answer (score 2):

Personal opinion: `@Transactional` + `@SpringBootTest` is (in a way) the same anti-pattern as `spring.jpa.open-in-view`. Yes, it's easy to get things working at first and having the automatic rollback is nice, but it loses you a lot of flexibility and control over your transactions. Anything that requires manual transaction management becomes very hard to test that way.

We recently had a very similar case and in the end we decided to bite the bullet and use `@DirtiesContext` instead. Yeah, tests take 30 more minutes to run, but as an added benefit the tested services behave the exact same way as in production and the tests are more likely to catch any transaction issues.

But before we did the switch, we considered using the following workaround:

1. Create an interface and a service similar to the following:

```java
interface TransactionService
{

    void runWithoutTransaction(Runnable runnable);

}
```

```java
@Service
public class RealTransactionService implements TransactionService
{

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public void runWithoutTransaction(Runnable runnable)
    {
        runnable.run();
    }

}
```

2. In your other service wrap the external http calls with the `#runWithoutTransaction`-Method, e.g.:

```java
@Service
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    private TransactionService transactionService;

    public void doStuff(UUID id)
    {
        transactionService.runWithoutTransaction(() -> {
            // call an external service
        })
    }
}
```

That way your production code will peform the `Propagation.NEVER` check, and for the tests you can replace the `TransactionService` with a different implemention that doesn't have the `@Transactional` annotations, e.g.:

```java
@Service
@Primary
public class FakeTransactionService implements TransactionService
{

    // No annotation here
    public void runWithoutTransaction(Runnable runnable)
    {
        runnable.run();
    }

}
```

This is not limited to `Propagation.NEVER`. Other propagation types can be implemented in the same way:

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void runWithNewTransaction(Runnable runnable)
{
    runnable.run();
}
```

And finally - the `Runnable` parameter can be replaced with a `Function`/`Consumer`/`Supplier` if the method needs to return and/or accept a value.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Your introduction pretty much sums up why we often do not use Transactional on our tests ... we don't want any bad surprises later.
I understand the concept of TransactionService, but as a rule, where I work we try to not to impact runtime code for tests. I don't think it's a compete test either : 
at runtime, if one service opens a transaction and calls the code with Transactional(NEVER), this would not be seen in tests.
I think truncating the tables after each test is preferable in that case (and quicker than DirtiesContext !, try it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is bit of wild idea, but if you are using mysql database, then maybe switch to [dolt](https://github.com/dolthub/dolt) for tests?

> Dolt is a SQL database that you can fork, clone, branch, merge, push and pull just like a git repository.

You can wrap it as [testcontainers container](https://docs.dolthub.com/introduction/installation/docker), load necessary data on start and then, on start of each test run [dolt reset](https://docs.dolthub.com/sql-reference/version-control/dolt-sql-procedures#dolt_reset).

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about dolt ... interesting. They indicate they are nearly 100% mysql compatible ... but still ... we used to test with h2, but it sometimes behaved differently than mariadb (even in mysql compat mode), that's why we switched to test containers. I'm a bit afraid to fall into the same problem with dolt...